# How forward message to other contact with telethon

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, telethon

How do I forward a message to another chat as soon as I receive it from a contact?
I created this example just to test routing, but it doesn't work.

```py
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
from telethon import TelegramClient, events

api_id = 9999900
api_hash = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash)
client.start()

@client.on(events.NewMessage)
async def main(event):
    await client.send_message('Other People', 'Hello!') #Don't work. Keeps waiting forever

with client:
    client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Answer (score 16):

```
@client.on(events.NewMessage)
async def main(event):
    await client.forward_messages(entity, event.message)
```

This code will work for forwarding new messages.

You can simply put `chat_id` of target user in place of `entity`

Comment: Unfourtenately, if message is medaGroup it splits to multiple